# Upgrading to a better quality camera before a wildlife-focused vacation

Tags: nikon, dslr, zoom, camera-recommendation, safari

I'm sure this has been asked many times before, but anything would be helpful.  I'm looking to upgrade from a standard point-and-shoot to a higher quality camera before a safari vacation.  I was leaning more towards dslr than mirorless, but am overwhelmed by determining mm v. zoom factor.  I'm mildly intimidated by breaking the think while trying to change lenses, but I want to make sure I will be able to get good quality photos of wildlife that might be further in the distance, as well as something that will be able to shoot quickly.  I was leaning toward the Nikon D3300.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Whatever you decide to get, get it soon so you can get used to it before you go.  Take it birding, as birds make you want long focal length.  You will learn the controls and how to hold it steady.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it you should honestly just invest in a nice point and shoot. If you buy a DSLR for the trip you're going to want a zoom that's 200mm or so which can get pricey. And unless you know what you're doing with the camera and can quickly adjust ISO, Shutter, f. stop, etc... you're going to be shooting it in auto mode anyway which would essentially make it a big expensive point and shoot. Point and shoot cameras these days are also getting extremely nice and can take amazing quality photos. The only downside to a point and shoot is you can't change the lenses which is only an issue if you want a lense with a lower f stop, wide angle, or very telephoto which can run thousands of dollars.

Look at [this zoom range](https://i.imgur.com/NTUu0u5.webm) on a coolpix point and shoot... you'd have a very hard and expensive time trying to get that kind of range on a DSLR